# Emulate a mouse click without using the actual mouse on linux

Tags: python, linux

I am working with a program that collects a lot of data then shows it to you in the program. Unfortunately, the program is poorly designed and requires you to "approve" each bit of data collected manually by clicking a checkbox to approve it. In order to automate this process, I wrote a small script that scans for a checkbox, clicks it, then clicks "next item".

Unfortunately, this requires moving the actual mouse, meaning I can't use my computer until the program has finished. There are other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720968/win32-simulate-a-click-without-simulating-mouse-movement) that [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319485/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-without-interfering-with-actual-mouse-in-python) automating this with the winapi, however none of these work on Linux. What is a way to automate this on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply start the program in a separate X server, for example using xvfb with

```
xvfb-run YOUR_PROGRAM
```

If you want to wrap just the instrumented program, that's possible too:

```
export DISPLAY=:42
Xvfb :42
THE_INSTRUMENTED_PROGRAMM
xdotool mousemove 1 1 click 1 # your instrumentation goes here
```

Comment: Yes, both programs need to run in the same X server. With option 1 (`xvfb-run`, you start a wrapper program that kicks off both the data collection program and your bot). With option 2, replace `THE_INSTRUMENTED_PROGRAM` with the program you're instrumenting (you call it `data collection program`) and `xdotool ...` with your bot.